# Load new page on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a master page that has a usercontrol on the left side of the page with a dropdown. When the user selects a value from the dropdown I need to load a different aspx page.  The new page has a similar (but not the same) looking usercontrol on the left and different content on the right.  How can I do this? Also, when the new page is loaded the dropdown must remember its selection.

Comment: Is this just asp.net or asp.net mvc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you want to use Javascript.  If you do, then try this JQuery method.

// Only load once page is fully loaded.

```
$(function()
{
  // Assume that the dropdownlist's id is TheList
  $('#TheList').change(function(e){
    var target = $(this).val();
    if(target.length > 0)
    {
       // go to new URL
       window.location.replace("http://www.locationurl.com/"+target);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the part of the question about setting the value of the dropdown on the next page, but nice client side answer.

Comment: This solution is more flexible because it will work within a callback

Answer (score 1):

Set `AutoPostback` to true on your dropdown.  Handle `OnSelectedChanged` and then pass the selected value to the next page on a Response.Redirect:

```
Response.Redirect(String.Format("NextPage.aspx?selected={0}", MyDropDownList.SelectedValue));
```

Then in your new page, check for that query parameter and set the SelectedValue of your drop down appropriately.

Comment: Not very elegant because of the postback, but I don't see a way around that.

Comment: As elegant as it's going to get as far as I can see for what you want to do.

Comment: This is a good solution, but it will not work during a callback.